# condensing/reducing vertical spacing between widgets in tkinter (Python) (AKA: setting vertical line/text spacing/padding)

Tags: python, tkinter, spacing

Here's my program:

```
import tkinter as tk 

#Create main window object 
root = tk.Tk()

#build GUI
for i in range(5):
    tk.Label(root, text="hello", height=0).grid(row=i)

#mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

It produces the following (running in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS)

[image]

Notice all that extra vertical space between the lines of text. I don't want that! How do I decrease it?

If I run this code instead:

```
import tkinter as tk 

#Create main window object 
root = tk.Tk()

#build GUI
for i in range(5):
    tk.Label(root, text="hello", height=0).grid(row=i)
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, i, weight=1) #allow vertical compression/expansion to fit window size after manual resizing

#mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

...it opens up and *initially looks exactly the same as before,* but now I can *manually* drag the box vertically to shrink it, like so:

[image]

Notice how much more vertically-compressed it is! **But, how do I do this programatically**, so I don't have to *manually* drag it to make it this way? I want to set this tight vertical spacing from the start, but no matter which parameters I change in `Label`, `grid`, or `rowconfigure` I can't seem to make it work without me manually dragging the box with the mouse to resize and vertically compress the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically modify the geometry just before starting the main loop instead of manually dragging it (change 0.6 to whatever % reduction you want):

```
import tkinter as tk  

#Create main window object 
root = tk.Tk()

#build GUI
for i in range(5):
    label = tk.Label(root, text = 'hello')
    label.grid(row=i)
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, i, weight=1) #allow vertical compression/expansion to fit window size after manual resizing

#mainloop
root.update()
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(root.winfo_width(), int(0.6*root.winfo_height())))
root.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot of the result running on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with Python 3.5.2:

[image]

Comment: this isn't a good general solution; it only works in very specific situations which aren't likely to come up in the real world.  While it works in this very specific case, it wouldn't work if there was another widget that you _didn't_ want to shrink.

Comment: @Nehal J Wani, thanks for this answer, as I really think it's quite useful, meets my intent for my application, and certainly puts another tool in my toolbag. I am very pleased with how it works. I upvoted it. Now that I've seen how Bryan Oakley's answer works though too, I think I'm going to mark it as the correct answer. First though, let me stick a screenshot of your results into your answer. If you can accept my edit please do.

Comment: Nehal, by the way, it looks like `update_idletasks()` is preferred over using `update()`. See here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method. Is there a certain reason you chose `update()` instead of `update_idletasks()` in your example?

Comment: @GabrielStaples No particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to affect vertical spacing.

When you use `grid` or `pack` there are options for padding (eg: `pady`, `ipady`, `minsize`). Also, the widget itself has many options which control its appearance. For example, in the case of a label  you can set the `borderwidth`, `highlightthickness` and `pady` values to zero in order to make the widget less tall.

Different systems have different default values for these various options, and for some of the options the default is something bigger than zero. When trying to configure the visual aspects of your GUI, the first step is to read the documentation, and look for options that affect the visual appearance. Then, you can start experimenting with them to see which ones give you the look that you desire.

In your specific case, this is about the most compact you can get:

```
label = tk.Label(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, pady=0, text="hello")
label.grid(row=i, pady=0, ipady=0)
```

Comment: Bryan, please see my edit to your answer to see if it is acceptable. I added screenshots and a link to Nehal Wani's answer, since even with all of the widths minimized I still don't get as much control as I'd like, making his technique indispensable, and the only way, in some scenarios. If you can accept my edit, please do, and I plan on marking your answer as correct, with those edits.

Comment: Bryan, as far as reading documentation goes, I've been using Effbot, as I don't know any other good alternative for tkinter. Do you have any other recommendations? For `grid` and `Label`, for instance, I read here (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) and here (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm), respectively.